# Installation of factoextra package in R studio

Tags: r, installation

I am trying to install `factoextra` package in R Studio (v.1.2.1335 on Mac), however, I get error messages for each of the several approaches I tried.

I tried simple installation as well as installing the package source from https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/factoextra/index.html.

```
install.packages("factoextra")

install.packages("~/Desktop/factoextra_1.0.5.tar.gz", repos = NULL, type = "source")
```

> package ‘factoextra’ is available as a source package but not as a binary
>
> Warning in install.packages :
>       package ‘factoextra’ is not available (for R version 3.1.2)

When installing the package source I get an error message:

> Warning in strptime(xx, f <- "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS", tz = tz) :
>       unknown timezone 'zone/tz/2019a.1.0/zoneinfo/America/Toronto'
>   ERROR: dependency ‘ggpubr’ is not available for package ‘factoextra’
>   * removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.1/Resources/library/factoextra’
>   Warning in install.packages :
>       installation of package ‘/Users/lihieder/Desktop/factoextra_1.0.5.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status

I also tried installing package `ggpubr` but run into similar issues even when trying to install the source package for ggpubr.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried updating your R installation to the current 3.6.0? Your version is 5 years old.

Comment: Tried updating R (in addition to R studio). It worked!. Many Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

only use

> install.packages("factoextra")